# Get the values of an array from indices in another array: Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 20x1 double array `A`, and a 1000x1 double array `B`.

I want to get array `C`, where array `C` will be 1000x1 double where the values in `B` are used to index the values in `A` like so:

```
C(1) = A(B(1))
C(2) = A(B(2))
...
C(i) = A(B(i))
...
c(1000) = A(B(1000))
```

How this can be done?

Comment: The title is very misleading. I thought you were trying couple Matlab instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this, you can directly use:

```
C = A(B)
```

This takes advantage of MATLAB's matrix indexing, which is the way indexing is handled in MATLAB when an array is used instead of an integer.

Take a look at the docs: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html

For example:

```
A = [11 12 13];
B = [1 2 3 1 2 3 3 2 1];
C = A(B)

C =

11    12    13    11    12    13    13    12    11
```

Ensure that B only contains integers which are valid indices of A (not less than 1 or greater than the length of A).

Answer (score 0):

I did it using for loop as shown below, not sure if this is the ideal solution:

```
C = zeros(1000,1);

for i = 1:1000
    C(i,1) = A(B(i));
end
```